# scipy's direct fails (almost) immediately on this toy optimization problem

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

Consider the following simple MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import  direct
def score(x):
    parity_in_range = len([v for v in x if 4 <= v <= 6])%3
    main_score = np.max(np.abs(np.diff(x)))
    return main_score + parity_in_range
length = 20
bounds = [(0,10)] * length
result = direct(score, locally_biased=False, bounds=bounds, maxiter=10000, maxfun=10000)
print(result)
```

An optimal solution is to make all the parameters equal and not between 4 and 6. E.g. all 3s.  This gives a function value of 0.  The optimization works with varying degrees of success with the different optimizers of scipy but it fails almost instantly with direct. It gives:

```
 message: The volume of the hyperrectangle containing the lowest function value found is below vol_tol=1e-16
 success: True
  status: 4
     fun: 2.0
       x: [ 5.000e+00  5.000e+00 ...  5.000e+00  5.000e+00]
     nit: 2
    nfev: 157
```

I am not sure that it should report success but the real problem is that it gives up after 157 function evaluations with that warning.

Is there any way to get direct to optimize this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The termination parameter `vol_tol` implicitly depends on the number of dimensions of the problem. The search space is divided up into a series of hyperrectangles, with the smallest middle hyperrectangle having a size of (1/3)^n, where n is the number of dimensions.

With n=20, this means that the innermost cube will have a volume of 2.8e-10. If that innermost cube's midpoint happens to be the lowest point, then that cube will be subdivided again. Since `vol_tol` defaults to 1e-16, this means that the algorithm will exit after only two iterations.

If you don't want `vol_tol` to cause DIRECT to exit early, you can set `vol_tol` to zero:

```
result = direct(score, locally_biased=False, bounds=bounds, maxiter=10000, maxfun=10000, vol_tol=0)
```

Running this, it finds a better solution, though still not an optimal one:

```
 message: Number of function evaluations done is larger than maxfun=10000
 success: False
  status: 1
     fun: 1.1111111111111112
       x: [ 3.889e+00  3.889e+00 ...  5.000e+00  5.000e+00]
     nit: 12
    nfev: 12021
```

Of course, you could also solve this problem by making the function simpler, e.g. making the `parity_in_range` objective leaky.

#### Altering the objective function to be continuous

It's frequently easier to optimize an objective function if that function is continuous.

In the following graph, the blue line represents the existing `parity_in_range` function for each value, ignoring the mod 3.

The orange line represents a new function, which slopes down toward the edge, giving the optimizer a hint that there is a lower value in that direction.

[image: objective function graph]

First, define the primitives that make up this curve. I'm using a sigmoid function as a continuous approximation of the step function.

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
```

Next, we need to be able to shift the center of this function around, and make the sigmoid function curve up and down faster.

```
def sigmoid_at_center(x, center, strength=1):
    return sigmoid((x - center) * strength)
```

Next, define the parity function as a sigmoid centered at 4, minus a sigmoid centered at 6. The strength parameter is set to 10.

```
def get_leaky_parity(x):
    return sigmoid_at_center(x, 4, 10) - sigmoid_at_center(x, 6, 10)
```

Finally, define the score function in terms of this function.

```
def score(x):
    parity_in_range = get_leaky_parity(x).sum()
    main_score = np.max(np.abs(np.diff(x)))
    return main_score + parity_in_range
```

You can then use the following code to use DIRECT to optimize this. I found that local bias made it able to solve it much faster.

```
result = direct(score, locally_biased=True, bounds=bounds, vol_tol=0, len_tol=0.001)
```

With this change to the objective function, it's able to solve this problem in up to 96 dimensions.

Sources used: [Lipschitzian Optimization
Without the Lipschitz Constant](http://www.planchet.net/EXT/ISFA/1226.nsf/769998e0a65ea348c1257052003eb94f/f9ca730ca27def69c12576d8002ed895/$FILE/Jones93.pdf)

Comment: What does it mean to make it leaky?

Comment: @Simd I mean changing it so that instead of instantly going from 0 to 1 in that range, it goes up and down more slowly. The effect of this is that an optimizer will know to move toward the edge. Here's a plot of how the objective function looks for each variable: https://i.imgur.com/Fdf5YoU.png I made this function from two sigmoid curves. Using this plus local bias allows it to solve this problem pretty much instantly. I can add code for this if it's useful to you.

Comment: Yes please. That would be really great, thank you.

Comment: @Simd I've added a section on changing the objective function to make it easier to optimize.

Comment: Would this ever find an optimal solution where the number of parameters between 4 and 6 is exactly 3?

Comment: @Simd Those solutions woudn't be optimal. If there is a solution where three of the parameters are between 4 and 6, then that implicitly means that some of the parameters are not between 4 and 6, and the optimizer can improve the main_score term by changing all parameters to the same value.